# Getting an error with an observable value but no locally, only on the server (: NullInjectorError: No provider for e!)

Tags: angular, express, observable, nodejs-server

I'm facing an error with an observable response in subscribe().
But weird thing is that happens only on my online app, locally, with same files and code, it's running as excepted.

```js
    export class TestObservableComponent implements OnInit {
      public chartSub: Subscription;
    
      private userData = [];
    
    constructor(
        public usersService: UsersService
    
    
        ) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.reloadUsers();
    
    
        this.pendingUsers$ = this.allUsers$
        .pipe(
          map(users => users
            .filter(user => user.is_verified === false))
        );
    
        this.chartSub = this.allUsers$
        .pipe(
          map(users => users
            .map(user => user.created))
        )
        .subscribe((res) => {
          for(let item of res) {
            this.userData.push(item);
          }
          console.log(this.userData);
        });
      }
    }
```

```html
<div *ngIf='(allUsers$ | async) as users' class="row">
  <div class="admin-panel-container">
    <div id="adminRef" class="admin-panel">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
          <div class="primal-stat">
            <div class="cont">
              <i class="user-icon"></i>
              <span class="number registered">{{ users.length }}</span>
              <span class="description">registered users</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf='(pendingUsers$ | async) as pendingUsers;' class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
          <div class="primal-stat">
            <div class="cont">
              <i class="user-pending-icon"></i>
            <span class="number pending">{{ pendingUsers.length }}</span>
            <span class="description">pending users</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="mt-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="chart-wrapper">
            <canvas baseChart
                [datasets]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [colors]="lineChartColors"
                [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
                [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
            </canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 2rem;" class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
          <div class="custom-table user-table">
            <div class="head">
              <div class="one">
                <span>date</span>
              </div>
              <div class="two">
                <span>pseudo</span>
              </div>
              <div class="three">
                <span>email</span>
              </div>
              <div class="four">
                <span>status</span>
              </div>
              <div class="five">
                <span>role</span>
              </div>
              <div class="six">
                <span>colonies</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
              <div *ngFor="let user of users; index as i" class="line">
                <div class="one">
                  <span>{{ user.created | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="two">
                  <span>{{ user.pseudo }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="three">
                  <span>{{ user.email }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="four">
                  <span [ngClass]="user.is_verified ? 'verified' : 'unverified'">{{ user.is_verified ? 'verified' : 'unverified' }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="five">
                  <i *ngIf="user.role === 'admin'" class="crown-icon"></i>
                  <span>{{ user.role }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="six">
                  <div class="d-flex"></div>
                  <span>{{ user.coloCount.length }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**So when i console.log locally i got this**

[image]

**And when i run it on server with exactly the same code, i got this**

[image]

I should give you the precision that on server, error will not occurs if i just try *console.log(res)*, it will correctly display the res array.
Error occurs when i start to do some manipulations on it like *this.userData.push(res)*

Any idea of what is going on ? Any help or leads greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have a guess that inside of your template you have something like `*ngFor="let item of userData"> <my-other-component></...>` and this <my-other-component is a source of this issue. to help you with that, the otherComponent code is required

Comment: no i don't have that logic as i can only subscribe asynchronously in templater OR in the ts file. i updated my post so you can view the template side

Comment: is the issue reproducible when you try locally `ng serve --prod` ?

Comment: this also could be a reason of your issue : https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/1255